# Partially suppress labels in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to plot "Decision Trees" using the "rpart.plot" library as shown below:

```
#load libraries
    library(rpart)
    library(rpart.plot)

#load data
    data(iris)

#fit rpart model (i.e. decision tree)
    r = rpart(Species ~., data=iris)

#plot model
    rpart.plot(r)
```

[image]

I have noticed that sometimes the labels in this picture will say "iris$Petal.Length" and sometimes they will just say "Petal.Length".

**Question:** Is there a way to "suppress" these labels and always show the labels without the name of the dataset and the "$" symbol? I.e. Is it always possible to show the labels as only "Petal.Length" ?  (So that they always look like the image I have posted)

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example where you do not get the labels you want? It's hard to fix something that isn't broke.

Comment: In which situation does the program prints the dataset name in the plot? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may define the model like this:

```
r = rpart(iris$Species ~iris$Petal.Length)
```

in this case, you'll see the dataset name in the labels

always try to use your dataset in the rpart() function like this:

```
r = rpart(Species ~., data=iris)
```